# Switching on / off X11 forwarding for remote firefox / git

Tags: linux, ssh, git, xorg, x11-forwarding

I'm using Ubuntu16 inside a Docker image on top of CentOS6 in order to be able to run certain desktop apps that doesn't run on top of CentOS6.

As an example, to run the Dartium browser, I do:

```
ssh -X -p 32768 docker@0.0.0.0 dartium
```

To run a special version of firefox, I do:

```
ssh -X -p 32768 docker@0.0.0.0 firefox-mod
```

etc, etc, etc - for each app I want to run on Ubuntu that doesn't work on CentOS6, I simply run it via `ssh -X`

One of the applications requires access to a git repo. I've setup all the SSH keys that rerequired to make it work and this is as far as I get:

```
$ git fetch origin
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 55: Bad configuration option: x11forwarding
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

The git remote is setup to run via SSH, when it runs, it obviously includes the x11forwarding parameter which is required for `ssh -X` to work. Removing `x11forwarding` config makes it work again, but then X11 Forwarding stops working.

```
ssh -T git@gitlab._____.____ -p 22 
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 55: Bad configuration option: x11forwarding
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

Is there a way to turn off the `x11forwarding` only for the `git` command?

Comment: Rather than enabling X11 forwarding for all hosts, why not enable it selectively in a host section?

Comment: I could probably do that as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such option as `x11forwarding` in `ssh_config` (it is server option for `sshd_config`). It is `ForwardX11` in `ssh_config`, as visible from manual page. Fix this typo in the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and it will work for you.

You can also set up `Host` blocks:

```
Host gitlab._____.____
  ForwardX11 no
```

in the `ssh_config` to disable that only for this host.

Comment: That fixes it and X11Forwarding continues to work, yay :-D
Thanks Jakuje!

Comment: Just a clarification. You need to put exclusion at the top rather than bottom of "Host *". I simply used "Host github.com" under which I put "ForwardX11 no"